# git branch overview

Tags: git

I know how to list the remote branches but is there a way to display how these branches related to each other? Under X I use gitk --all for this but this isn't an option when using a ssh connection.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What about u can use

```
ssh -X <login name>@<hostname>
```

if you have installed X server. so that you can display remote's GUI on the local machine.

Another option is that you can use VNC to help this.

Answer (score 0):

The closest equivalent to `--all` for gitk in a terminal command is `git log --all`; they use the same underlying commit selection options. If you only want some branches you can use `git log A B C`. To see ASCII-art commit graph, use `--graph`.

I use this variant quite a lot:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```